# Resource model validation failure in JerseyTest for Spring-Jersey application

Tags: spring, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I have an annotated Spring-Jersey application. I am trying to set up unit test for my controllers using `JerseyTest`. I am getting the following errors on running the test that I am not able to figure out. What have I missed?

```
SEVERE: Following issues have been detected: 
WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public com.example.services.dto.UnitDto com.example.apis.UnitResource.getUnits(com.example.services.dto.PointDto) throws com.example.exceptions.PointOutsideBounds at index 2.

Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public com.example.services.dto.UnitDto com.example.apis.UnitResource.getUnits(com.example.services.dto.PointDto) throws com.example.exceptions.PointOutsideBounds at index 2.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.example.apis.UnitResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@31a5870e]}, definitionMethod=public com.example.services.dto.UnitDto com.example.apis.UnitResource.getUnits(com.example.services.dto.PointDto) throws com.example.exceptions.PointOutsideBounds, parameters=[Parameter [type=class com.example.services.dto.PointDto, source=contains, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class com.example.services.dto.UnitDto}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
```

The controller class is as follows:

```
@Component
@Path("/app/units")
public class UnitResource {
    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    private Request request;

    @Inject
    private UnitService unitService;

    @Inject
    public UnitResource(@Named("UnitService") UnitService unitService) {
        this.unitService = unitService;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Timed(absolute = true, name = "getUnitForPoint")
    public UnitDto getUnits(@QueryParam("contains") @NotNull PointDto point) throws PointOutsideBounds {
        return unitService.getUnitForPoint(point);
    }
}
```

The test class is as follows:

```
public class UnitResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Mock
    private UnitService unitService;

    @Override
    protected ResourceConfig configure() {
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
        //      .register(new UnitResource(Mockito.mock(UnitService.class))) -- has the same effect
                .register(UnitResource.class)
                .property("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class));

        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, "0");

        return rc;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new InMemoryTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUnit() throws PointOutsideBounds {

        Response response = target()
                .path("/app/units")
                .queryParam("contains", new Point(0.0,0.0).toJson())
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .get();

        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(Response.Status.OK));
    }
}
```

The application configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean(name="UnitService")
    public UnitService unitService() {
        return new UnitService();
    }
}
```

My Gradle dependencies for test configuration are:

```
dependencies {
    // Using junit-dep package to get junit without hamcrest dependency
    testCompile("junit:junit-dep:4.8.2")
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.4")
    testCompile ('org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:2.22.2')
    testCompile('org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory:2.22.2')
}

configurations {
    testCompile.exclude group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', module: 'jersey-spring3'
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28620966/341008) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33767038/341008) but neither solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** For the most part, this answer applies to all `@XxxParam` annotated parameters.

The `PointDto` parameter seems to be the problem

```
public UnitDto getUnits(@QueryParam("contains") @NotNull PointDto point)
```

Query parameters are Strings. Jersey has the capability to convert that String to some basic types like `int`, `boolean`, `Date`, etc. But it has no idea how to create the `PointDto` from that String. That doesn't mean that we can't use custom types. We just need to follow some rules:

1. Have a constructor that accepts a String. Then we need to construct the object ourselves from that String. For example

   ```
   public PointDto(String param) {
       Map<String, Object> map = parseJson(param);
       this.field1 = map.get("field1");
       this.field2 = map.get("field2");
   }
   ```

   It's a bit of work.
2. Another option is to have a static `fromString(String)` or static `valueOf(String)` in the class. Jersey will invoke this method to construct the object. So for instance you can have in your `PointDto` class

   ```
   public static PointDto fromString(String param) {
       PointDto dto = parseJson(param);
       return dto;
   }
   ```
3. You can have a `ParamConverterProvider`. I won't put an example, but you can read more in [this good article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/11/inject-custom-java-types-via-jax-rs-parameter-annotations/) about how you can implement it. You can also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32677962/2587435)

Note, the information presented in this answer is in the javadoc for [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html).

Comment: Thanks. Completely missed that. I am reconsidering passing JSON as query parameter. I will send a comma separated string like `x,y,z` and initialise `PointDto` inside the controller.

Comment: As an aside, I noticed you are excluding Spring from the test deps. I'm guessing it's because you are getting the filenotfoundexception from Jersey when it tries to look for the Spring xml context file. You can have a look at the configuration in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34990765/2587435) for how you can use the annotation config. That way you can use different Spring profiles for your tests, instead of having to use mocks for everything. Just thought I'd bring it up.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I am writing unit tests now so I do need to mock everything. But I will use this when developing integration tests.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Looking at your code again, you are already doing this :-) I'm not much of a Gradle user, so maybe I am misunderstanding what `testCompile.exclude` means